# Why does instance_of?(Hash) return wrong result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash which is `h = {"1"=>"0-20%"}`

I check `h.instance_of?(Hash)` which should return `false` but it returns `true`.

Why?

Comment: Er, why do you think it should return false?

Comment: Perhaps (guessing hard) the OP thinks that if you use the literal notation it's not the same as calling `Hash.new`?

Comment: I think the OP needs to [read the docs](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Object#instance_of%3F-instance_method) and adjust his premise, and either change, or delete, the question.

Answer (score 4):

`h` is an instance of the Hash Class and

as per [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001032):

> Returns true if obj is an instance of
>   the given class. See also
>   Object#kind_of?.

Thus by definition `h.instance_of?(Hash)` will return true.

Comment: What about if I need to check the value is a hash or not. How can I do that? cos for now I have a hash which is a value can be hashes.

Comment: You can do `h["1"].instance_of?(Hash)`

Comment: "What about if I need to check the value is a hash or not". You do it the same way, only you test that value, not the containing hash. Everything in Ruby is an object, and all objects inherit from Object, which contains the `instance_of?` method you are using.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `instance_of`. Probably you want to do `instance_of?`. It should return true because it is a hash.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. But missed execution context of the code. It should be mention that question has ruby-on-rails tag.

I don't know particular but in some cases your `Hash` can be promoted to `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`. And this causes `instance_of?` to return `false`.

In that cases use `kind_of?`.